# node js параметры из командной строки

Tags: node.js

Коллеги, пытаюсь подчинить себе node.js.
Есть файл - `calc.js`

Его полное содержимое:

```
var nodePath = process.argv[0];
var value = Number(process.argv[1]);
var rate = Number(process.argv[2]);
var total = 0;
total = value * rate;
console.log("nodePath: " + nodePath);
console.log();
console.log(total);
```

при запуске его в Windows 10 PowerShell nodePath дает нормальный результат, а дальше идёт NaN

хочу:

1. понять почему этот недвусмысленный код выдает NaN? и как его отредактировать, чтобы так не было?
2. понять, требует ли node.js загрузки файлов на сервер, как это требует php для исполнения скриптов?

делал:

1. документацию node.js читал, не понял в чем мой косяк
2. русскоязычные форумы и сообщества читал, тема не очень популярная

Comment: Косяк в том, что Вы не понимаете, что делает код....Мне кажется, что прежде, чем пытаться подчинить `NodeJs`, Вам необходимо еще сам `JS` выучить.... это я без всякой злости говорю...просто констатация факта. П.С. минус не мой)

Comment: А какого результата вы ожидали и почему?

Comment: @Дмытрык спасибо за невероятнейший конструктив и идею, теперь когда ко мне будут обращаться ко вопросам, в которых я компетентен, буду отвечать - учите матчасть)) зачем обмен опытом, если каждый может изучить абсолютно всё и не задавать никаких вопросов

Comment: @AlexeyTen хотелось бы перевести два параметра в числа, перемножить их и вывести математический ответ

Comment: А вы параметры-то указали? Как вы запускали этот скрипт?

Comment: Ааа. В argv[1] лежит путь к скрипту. Ваши параметры идут дальше.

Comment: @AlexeyTen эту информацию я нашел в документации. Нет ли возможности заменить argv[1] на простую переменную? Запускаю так - node calc.js 2 2

Comment: `NaN` - это базовые знания в `JS`. При наличии этих знаний, Вы смогли бы понять, что, как минимум, один из множителей в строке `total = value * rate` не является числом...дальше цепочка рассуждений привела бы Вас к вопросу, что же такое `process.argv[1]`, `process.argv[2]`, да и вообще `process.argv`... и тогда, Вы сами смогли бы понять, в чем проблема....

Comment: Таки что мешает взять argv[2] и argv[3]?

Comment: @AlexeyTen задача стоит передать первый параметр именно в argv[1]

Comment: Не может задача так стоять. Это ваша фантазия какая-то

Comment: @AlexeyTen увы, может. Фантазия моя здорова, ибо node я практически не знаю. Где-то находил инфу, как подменить [0] и [1] обычными переменными, но сейчас не могу никак ни в истории браузера не в гугле найти...

Comment: @Дмытрык вы гений! честно! что такое NaN я знаю, про базовые штуки JS мне тоже рассказывать не нужно, за помощью обращаюсь не ожидая получить посылы и философию, спасибо за понимание

Comment: Нафига? У вас цель перемножить числа, а не ломать стандартное поведение ноды. Тем более вы её ещё не знаете

Comment: Параметры начинаются с цифры 2 — это данность и не нужно хотеть её менять

Comment: @AlexeyTen вы в армии бывали? Там природа говорит, что трава должна быть зеленая, а полковник говорит, что синяя, и трава становится синяя

Comment: Мы тут не в армии и для любого "надо" должна быть причина. Для такого идиотского "надо" должна быть очень серьёзная причина. И если бы мне пришла такая задача по работе, я бы усомнился во вменяемости автора

Comment: В итоге разобрался сам - передаю данные методом названия файла, парсю строку process.argv[1], отрезаю расширение и путь, преобразую в число, готово

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге разобрался сам - передаю данные методом названия файла, парсю строку, отрезаю расширение и путь, преобразую в число, готово

В итоге должно быть что-то вроде

```
var value = Number(process.argv[1].replace(/\D+/g,""));
```

Этот код просто дёргает цифры из строки, но в итоговом результате я допилил его до ума, так чтобы цифры брались только из названия файла (на случай если в пути будут левые цифры).

Answer (score 2):

Потому что `process.argv[0]` путь к ноде, а `process.argv[1]` к скрипту который запущен, поэтому вам нужны process.argv[2] и process.argv[3] если я правильно понял
ссылка на доку [process.argv](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv)